# Pandas Melt function for time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to melt my pandas data frame but I am not quiet sure how to assign the variables properly. I looked through the other examples on stack but I can't seem to find a variation matching this. My data frame (df1) looks like this :

```
[IN]: df1
[OUT]:
             40025.0    21201.0       30061.0   46021.0
date                
2020-08-08  0.000861    0.001292    0.000287    0.001177
2020-08-09  0.001147    0.001290    0.000344    0.001204
2020-08-10  0.001431    0.001288    0.000401    0.001231
```

Each column is for a different FIPS code, the values are the number of Covid cases per day (this data has been processed for future clustering) and index is a datetime index (day). The data frame is 804 columns by 470 rows. I would like my data frame to look like this:

[image]

I know I can make this work if I leave "date" as a  column (as opposed to the index) by doing this:

```
df1 =df1.melt(id_vars="date", var_name="FIPS", value_name="Covid_cases")
```

But if I do that, then I get an error when trying to convert the "date" column as the index. I need it the index to be a datetime index because I am going to kmeans cluster the time series data and then plot time series clusters. Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `id_vars`, you should've used `ignore_index=False` (by default it is set to True). With `ignore_index=True`, pandas will not reset your index before unpivoting.

```
>>> df1 = df1.melt(var_name='FIPS', value_name='Cases', ignore_index=False)
>>> df1
               FIPS     Cases
date
2020-08-08  40025.0  0.000861
2020-08-09  40025.0  0.001147
2020-08-10  40025.0  0.001431
2020-08-08  21201.0  0.001292
2020-08-09  21201.0  0.001290
2020-08-10  21201.0  0.001288
2020-08-08  30061.0  0.000287
2020-08-09  30061.0  0.000344
2020-08-10  30061.0  0.000401
2020-08-08  46021.0  0.001177
2020-08-09  46021.0  0.001204
2020-08-10  46021.0  0.001231
```

Answer (score 2):

If `date` is currently the index, you should be able to `reset_index()` and then `set_index('date')` afterwards:

```py
df1 = (df1
    .reset_index()
    .melt(id_vars='date', var_name='FIPS', value_name='Covid_cases')
    .set_index('date')
)
```

```
               FIPS  Covid_cases
date                            
2020-08-08  40025.0     0.000861
2020-08-09  40025.0     0.001147
2020-08-10  40025.0     0.001431
2020-08-08  21201.0     0.001292
2020-08-09  21201.0     0.001290
2020-08-10  21201.0     0.001288
2020-08-08  30061.0     0.000287
2020-08-09  30061.0     0.000344
2020-08-10  30061.0     0.000401
2020-08-08  46021.0     0.001177
2020-08-09  46021.0     0.001204
2020-08-10  46021.0     0.001231
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can do this via `stack`.

```
df = (
    df.stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'level_1': 'FIPS', 0: 'Covid_cases'})
    .set_index('date')
)
```